# JavaScript "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null" with dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

So I've seen the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null` question come up a few times before. But none of those helped me. All of those answers seemed concerned with the code loading before the page had loaded fully or that there was something with the quotes or something.

The entire program has to be in a `window.onload` function for major parts of it to work (keeping divs hidden and such), so perhaps it's something to do with that? Also, I had to create the ID's of the checkboxes dynamically.

The code I am having trouble with looks like this:

```
var list = [document.getElementById("div1"), document.getElementById("div2")];
var form = [document.createElement("form"), document.createElement("form")];
var tradeValue = [0, 0];
var toBeTraded = {
    name: [[], [], [], [], []],
    x: [[], [], [], [], []],
    yru: [[], [], [], [], []],
    type: [[], [], [], [], []],
    value: [[], [], [], [], []],
    w: [[], [], [], [], []]
};
var player = {
    pNames: [[], [], [], [], []],
    pType: [[], [], [], [], []],
    pX: [[], [], [], [], []],
    pYRU: [[], [], [], [], []],
    pValue: [[], [], [], [], []],
};
var tradeInitiated = 0;
var trdsel = document.getElementById("tp2");
var tradee;
    var trade = {
    list: function (p, z) {
        for (var i = 0; i < player.pNames[p].length; i++) {
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
            checkBox.type = "checkbox";
            label.innerHTML = (player.pNames[p][i] + "    ");
            checkBox.id = z + "_" + i;
            label.appendChild(checkBox);
            form[z].appendChild(label);
        }
        list[z].appendChild(form[z]);
    },
    calc: function (k, z) {
        for (var i = 0; i < player.pNames[k].length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(z + "_" + i).checked === true) {
                tradeValue[z] = tradeValue[z] + player.pValue[k][i];
            }
        }
    },
    exch: function (k, l, z) {
        for (var i = 0; i < player.pNames[k].length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(z + "_" + i).checked === true) {
                if (player.pType[k][i] === "property") {
                    prop.id[player.pX[k][i]][player.pYRU[k][i]] = l;
                } else if (player.pType[k][i] === "rr") {
                    rr.id[player.pYRU[k][i]] = l;
                } else if (player.pType[k][i] === "utility") {
                    utils.id[player.pYRU[k][i]] = l;
                }
                monopolyTest();
                toBeTraded.name[k].push(player.pNames[k][i]);
                toBeTraded.x[k].push(player.pX[k][i]);
                toBeTraded.yru[k].push(player.pYRU[k][i]);
                toBeTraded.type[k].push(player.pType[k][i]);
                toBeTraded.value[k].push(player.pValue[k][i]);
                toBeTraded.w[k].push(i);
            }
        }
        trade.exchAct(k, l, z);
    },
    exchAct: function (k, l, z) {
        for (var i = 0; i < toBeTraded.name[k].length; i++) {
            player.pNames[l].push(toBeTraded.name[k][i]);
            player.pX[l].push(toBeTraded.x[k][i]);
            player.pYRU[l].push(toBeTraded.yru[k][i]);
            player.pType[l].push(toBeTraded.type[k][i]);
            player.pValue[l].push(toBeTraded.value[k][i]);
            tradeValue[z] = tradeValue[z] + toBeTraded.value[k][i];
            player.pNames[k].splice(toBeTraded.w[i], 1);
            player.pX[k].splice(toBeTraded.w[i], 1);
            player.pYRU[k].splice(toBeTraded[i], 1);
            player.pType[k].splice(toBeTraded[i], 1);
            player.pValue[k].splice(toBeTraded[i], 1);
        }
        toBeTraded.name = [[], [], [], [], []];
        toBeTraded.x = [[], [], [], [], []];
        toBeTraded.yru = [[], [], [], [], []];
        toBeTraded.type = [[], [], [], [], []];
        toBeTraded.value = [[], [], [], [], []];
        toBeTraded.w = [[], [], [], [], []];
    },
    prep: function () {
        tradee = document.getElementById("tp2").value;
        if (tradeInitiated === 0) {
            var tradeConfirmation = confirm("Would you like to trade with Player " + tradee + "?");
            if (tradeConfirmation === true) {
                tradeInitiated = 1;
                menu("trade");
                trade.list(turn, 0);
                trade.list(tradee, 1);
                trdsel.innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
        return tradee;
        $("#commenceTrade").on("click", function () { trade.act(); });
    },
    act: function () {
        alert("Player " + turn + ", allow Player " + tradee + " to access the computer to confirm the trade.");
        trade.calc(turn, 0);
        trade.calc(tradee, 1);
        var tradeIsOkay = confirm("Player " + tradee + ", look carefully. Are you alright with this trade? (Trade Value: " + tradeValue[0] + " vs. " + tradeValue[1] + ".)");
        if (tradeIsOkay === true) {
            trade.exch(turn, tradee, 0);
            trade.exch(tradee, turn, 1);
            trade.retSetup();
            console.log(prop.mnplTF);
            tradeValue[0] = 0;
            tradeValue[1] = 0;
        } else {
            tradeValue[0] = 0;
            tradeValue[1] = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

The weird problem is it is working in `trade.calc` but not `trade.exch`. Is there something obvious that I am missing? I am fairly new to JavaScript but my code *looks* right to me.

Also, `trade.act()` is called upon by a button press, but it only breaks at `trade.exch()`.

Comment: The error means `document.getElementById(z + "_" + i)` is returning `null`, i.e. it didn't find a node with that _id_ in the _#document_, log `z` and `i` and check that you're creating a node with such an _id_

Comment: I have, and with `z` = 0, and `i` = 0, the id is `0_0`. I can double check to see if I reversed it on accident elsewhere in the code, but I don't think I did.

Comment: @AaronBaldwin - "... but not trade.list" - you don't have `.checked` in `trade.list`.

Comment: Alright well it's returning three sets of values when it is supposed to be only two: `0_0` and `1_0`. But `1_1` is in there too.

Comment: @AaronBaldwin so check a node with _id_ `0_0` is generated in `.list()` and that `list[z]` is actually in the _DOM Tree_ (can't see how it's defined)

Comment: @Igor I meant `trade.exch`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PaulS. I also edited in relevant variables. Hopefully I have it all there, this is a smaller part of a program about 1000 lines long.